# Render inline PDF form and submit to .NET server

Tags: pdf, .net

I have a desired feature for a project I'm working on that I'm having trouble finding a tool to handle.  Here is the goal:

- Display a PDF form in the browser and allow the user to fill it out.
- Pre-populate certain form fields with data.
- Allow the user to submit the PDF to a .NET web server, retrieving the values in the various PDF form fields.
- Save a copy of the PDF the user completed.

Ideally this tool would be free.  The pre-population of data I would say is a nice to have.

Any recommendations?  Perhaps this will require more than one tool/library.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Adobe FDF Toolkit is old but still works and is free. In the documentation at the link below are suggested workflows that will show you how to prepopulate a PDF, submit it as though it were an HTML form so you can use any technology to parse it. You can also submit the entire, saved,  PDF as a big blob of data that you can store.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/fdftoolkit.html